# PHP "use" declarations repeated or with a comma?

Tags: php, coding-style

I was curious to know, when declaring use statements with PHP at the start of a class, why the "use" keyword is generally repeated in each line even though it is
possible to put a coma at the end off the line for the next declaration, like the following:

```
namespace Behat\Mink;

use Behat\Mink\Driver\DriverInterface,
    Behat\Mink\Selector\SelectorsHandler,
    Behat\Mink\Element\DocumentElement;
```

Unlike this:

```
namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

It is just to ease the copy/paste ? To mimic the import statements of Java ?
Or we just don't care... :)

Comment: With the second you can easily search your code for use statements (i.e. using grep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just for convenience to allow multiple statements on the same line. Here's an excerpt from the PHP documentation:

`PHP additionally supports a convenience shortcut to place multiple use statements on the same line`

Comment: Moreover I found something related in the PSR2 standards and they recommend to have one use per line. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#3-namespace-and-use-declarations